# Alternative array navigation hack in AS3 not running as defined :(

Tags: actionscript-3

for some reasons, this code does not want to work; its supposed to be a convenient alternative to using "arrays" for navigation buttons whereby the clicking of one button removes the click state from the rest  -

```
nav_mc.buttonMode=true;
nav_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, navOver);
nav_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, navOut);
nav_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, navClick);

nav_mc.nav1_mc.mouseChildren=false;
nav_mc.nav2_mc.mouseChildren=false;
nav_mc.nav3_mc.mouseChildren=false;
nav_mc.nav4_mc.mouseChildren=false;

var currentNav:MovieClip;

function navOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var navItem:MovieClip=e.target as MovieClip;
    trace(navItem.name);
    if (navItem!=currentNav) {
        navItem.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}

function navOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var navItem:MovieClip=e.target as MovieClip;
    if (navItem!=currentNav) {
        navItem.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

function navClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var navItem:MovieClip=e.target as MovieClip;
    if (currentNav!=null) {
        navItem.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    currentNav=navItem;
    navItem.gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

please, been on this for hours now, what am I missing out?

Comment: What does not work specifically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when I click on a new button, the previously clicked button doesnt go off unless I roll over and roll out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is: you should change the navItem variable to the currentNav, inside of the if block here:

```
if (currentNav!=null) {
   navItem.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

It looks like you want to make some changes to the current active item (currentNav).

UPD.: My advice is: try to change the code above to the next code

```
if (currentNav!=null) {
   currentNav.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

UPD 18-11-2015, Toggle buttons:

It's hard to say if my code works or not (I don't have the whole project to test it), but it looks like it should.

```
function navClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var navItem:MovieClip=e.target as MovieClip;
    if (currentNav != null)
    {
        currentNav.gotoAndStop(1);
    }

    if(currentNav == navItem)
    {
        currentNav = null;

    }else
    {
        currentNav = navItem;
        navItem.gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: for which function, the navout function or the navclick?

Comment: You have the only one if statement where currentNav is compared with null:

Comment: `function navClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var navItem:MovieClip=e.target as MovieClip;
    if (currentNav!=null) {
        navItem.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    currentNav=navItem;
    navItem.gotoAndStop(3);
}`

Comment: thanx for your help, the thing is I'm kind of new to as3, not too new but still green in major coding aspects. the code above is a sample i downloaded and was adapting  for my use. so its not my orginal work thus most apects  of the code such the variables definition like "CurrentNav" I have not been able 2 fully grasp its logic hence i just created a movie clip known as nav_mc with 3 child movieclips; nav1, nav2, nav3. the code originally made use of tween class for the button states but I decided to use frame to frame state which works just fine except for the above problem

Comment: You're welcome! Did my answer help solve your problem?

Comment: erm basically I dont really understand what you advising me to do; if you could break it down a little for my novice brain I will really appreciate seeing that the code is not really sumfin I totally wrote.

Comment: @FrancisStephen Just have updated the answer. Please, check it.

Comment: woah! thanks soo much, it actually worked, I'm grateful was just about to throw in the towel on this and ask u not to bother any longer. Thanks a bunch. Just on a side note, will it be possible to get a toggle functionality on any of the buttons were one button clicked to turn on can also be clicked to turn off ? Thanks alot for ur help:)

Comment: Hi! Please, check the main answer again, I've just updated it and added the code which should do toggle (at leat I hope for it). And, also, please forgive me, I edit the main topic (I wanted to edit my answer, but accidentally changed yours).

Comment: *tears of joy* :') thanx a million, I'm really greatful for your help. it works like charm. its interesting what a simple line of code can do/undo. i really do have a long way to go b4 i can be at your level: editing ones code to work without even having the project files. Thnx again